# Issues implementing a reduce in CUDA

Tags: c, parallel-processing, cuda

I am trying to implement a reduce in cuda, where I find the maximum element in an array. I have used this kernel for finding the minimum, and it works, but it doesnt work when I try to find the maximum. I have stepped through the algorithm repeatedly and can't find a bug. Any help would really be appreciated. (additionally, I get a different output when I uncomment the print statement there, which is also quite a headache....)

```
__global__
void findMaxAndMin(const float* const d_logLuminance, float* reduceCopy, int length, float* min_logLum, float* max_logLum){
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    if(idx >= length){
        return;
    }
    reduceCopy[idx] = d_logLuminance[idx];
    __syncthreads();

    //do a reduction with max

    for(int offset = 1;offset < length;offset = offset*2){
        if(idx % (offset*2) == 0){
            int compIdx = idx + offset;
            if(compIdx < length){
                float newVal = a_max(reduceCopy[idx], reduceCopy[compIdx]);
                if(idx == 0){
                    //printf("val %f \n", newVal);
                }
                __syncthreads();
                reduceCopy[idx] = newVal;
                __syncthreads();
            }
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if(idx == 0){
        *max_logLum = reduceCopy[0];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code. If it worked for minimum, you were lucky.

- I presume you launch more than one block (you use `blockIdx.x`). You repeatedly use the result of one block in another -- the `reduceCopy[compIdx]` may be set by another block. You cannot rely on this: you cannot predict the order of execution of the blocks or synchronize them. `__syncthreads()` is a barrier that works only within a single block!
- `if(idx >= length) return` is dangerous because it causes that not all threads will reach the following `__syncthreads`.
- you have `__syncthreads()` within a divergent conditional `if(compIdx < length)`.
- `a_max` is undefined. Remember to always include the minimum working example. I can guess what that function is supposed to do, but maybe there is yet another bug lurking within it?

It seems to me that you have a good understanding on parallel reduction in theory, but the implementation fails because of the CUDA-specific behavior.

I would suggest you read some examples on how to do parallel reduction specifically on CUDA.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I did not know about some of this cuda specific behavior... I will try to reimplement this. Thank you!